# Hindi subtitle (srt file) parsing issue

Tags: ios, swift, regex, parsing, subtitle

The NSRegularExpression in iOS couldn't parse the whole hindi srt file using the regex expression below:

```
(\\d+)\\n([\\d:,.]+)\\s+-{2}\\>\\s+([\\d:,.]+)\\n([\\s\\p{P}]*?(?=\\n{2,}|$))
```

The above expression is working fine with English subtitles. In case of hindi subtitle the result after the function

```
let matches = regex.matches(in:<SubtitleStringToParse>, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, <SubtitleStringToParse.count>))
```

gives matches array with lesser values as expected. If suppose actually there should be 10 matches, it is showing only 8 matches, rest 2  are missing. As long the hindi subtitles are we can see some number of missing matches towards the end.

Is there any way to resolve this issue or for different languages what should be done for parsing subtitles to get the accurate matches?

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Check https://github.com/niklasberglund/swubtitles

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. It worked well.Thank you very much. Also There is some mistake in the regex which I have mentioned. The  regex was supposed to be (\\d+)\\n([\\d:,.]+)\\s+-{2}\\>\\s+([\\d:,.]+)\\n([\\s\\S]*?(?=\\n{2,}|$))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression.

```
"((\\d+)\\n([\\d:,.]+)\\s+-{2}\\>\\s+[\\d:,.]+\\n[\\s\\S]*?(?=\\n{2,}|$))"
```

Comment: Thank you @Vipin. Updating the expression was good one. It too worked.